# Order by with special condition

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have Table1 with Column1:

```
Column1|
-------|
1 aaaa|
2 aaaa|
3 aaaa|
4 aaaa|
10 aaaa|
6 aaaa|
7 aaaa|
8 aaaa|
9 aaaa|
5 aaaa|
```

If I query:

```
Select * 
FROM Table1
Order By Column1
```

The output is:

```
1 aaaa
10 aaaa
2 aaaa  
3 aaaa
4 aaaa  
5 aaaa    
6 aaaa    
7 aaaa    
8 aaaa    
9 aaaa
```

What I would like is:

```
1 aaaa 
2 aaaa  
3 aaaa  
4 aaaa   
5 aaaa    
6 aaaa    
7 aaaa    
8 aaaa    
9 aaaa
10 aaaa
```

I know I can solve it by adding a 0 in front of the number 1 until 9.
But unfortunately I can not do this in the data - It must be in the query or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Select *
FROM Table1
Order By cast(SUBSTRING (Column1,1,charindex(' ',Column1)-1) as int)
```

Please check this [**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3a311/9)

Comment: With the test data it works :) Only with my real data I get the error: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. But that is not your fold ofcourse - sorry for this! This one works by the way: ORDER BY CAST(Left(Column1, CHARINDEX(' ', Column1)) AS int) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use "ASC" as below

```
Select * FROM `Table1` ORDER BY `Column1` ASC
```

Comment: Do you have two columns in your table? such ID and Name. Please use the ID column. Then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
SELECT C 
FROM Table_1 
ORDER BY CAST(Left(Column1, CHARINDEX(' ', Column1)) AS int)
```

Thanks everyone